# Windows 10 doesn't recognize second monitor

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a while to no avail. I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

My Lenovo Y700 laptop **no longer** recognizes my 24" Samsung monitor, at all. I've tried troubleshooting in several ways:

- My Xbox One shows up on the Samsung monitor but not with the correct
  resolution, so the monitor isn't broken
- My laptop works with my Panasonic TV
- I've tried hooking the laptop up to the Samsung monitor using several different HDMI cables
- I've tried updating my laptop graphics 
  drivers. I've failed to update the Intel 530 graphics driver as it says it's not working for my Lenovo laptop. Not sure if this would be of relevance

Let me know if you need any more details. Thanks in advance.
Grateful for any help I can get.

/Nils

Comment: Is the Samsung monitor using an HDMI or DVI port, are you using an adapter on the cable? How old is the monitor?

Comment: Have you seen this post, it is a different computer but just may work ...

Ok so I've settle things up.

I've called to the store and they gave me another new laptop. HDMI now works as expected. Also I was curious what was wrong and few days later I've called them and they told me that laptop's BIOS just needed an update. After that it worked fine..   https://superuser.com/questions/868545/second-monitor-not-recognized-after-boot-connected-to-new-laptop?rq=1

Comment: I ran a search for the laptop at lenovo and here is the link. Only you know which would be the correct laptop by number, Hope this helps. https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/search?query=Lenovo%20Y700%20laptop%20BIOS%20update  CLICK SUPPORT

Comment: Hi Vssher, and thanks for  your replies!
The monitor is about 3 years old, it's an S24D390 I believe. I'm not using an adapter, just pluggin into the HDMI port. 

Also, I tried with another laptop today, and still nothing happened. I guess I'll have to buy a new monitor, sigh..

Comment: Did anything I wrote help you, if so please let us all know, someone else might also gain from this. Have you tried updating the BIOS?

Comment: Also, thanks for the monitor input. Found this, there are drivers there, with manual downloads, could this help maybe ? https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/led-monitor-sd390-series

Comment: Have you tried the On Screen Display (OSD), usually, if this shows on screen then there is usually no problem with the monitor.

Comment: Hi again. I've now updated BIOS (the latest version was only slightly newer - from sept. 2016, v. 2.2) and updated my monitor driver. It shows up in the device manager but I still nothing shows up. 

The OSD seems to work, but I can only choose HDMI->PC/AV. Usually I can also change brightness, colors et al. The only reaction from the screen is that when I plug the HDMI cable into the laptop the monitor goes from "Check Signal Cable" to "HDMI". I'll attach two pictures showing this.

Thanks again.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g5zgt3z4WZO1kop4m9SycvzoVtoD7WHh
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g3oGULeT1Sbt2kV0bmL6cRk0xgNOmNh4

Comment: This is a good sign. The monitor is not dead, have you tried changing cables or using a different source. When you can get feedback from your monitor like this it usually indicates there is a solution to this, it is Not Dead ;-) Thanks for letting me know. Try switching cables maybe even trying another in, like DVI or VGA.

Comment: Hey guys. I know it's been a while but today I gave this monitor another try. I've managed to get 1080p looking perfect with my Xbox One, using the same HDMI cable that I tried with the laptop/desktop computers. In Xbox settings, for some reason I could only get a resolution of 640x480, but switching to DVI unlocked full HD for some reason. Still doesn't work with my PC, though. Any thoughts?